# Move interactive message bubble to app area

Tags: ios, ios-messages-extension, apple-business-chat

I'm writing a messages extension that is meant to work with Apple Business Chat. When receiving an interactive message, I would like to show a static bubble that the user taps to show more options down in the app area OR simply show my interactive area and not show a bubble.

How can I achieve one of these things?

My problem is that I have a small tableViewController for the user to interact with and it doesn't play well in the message bubble area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JSON, use the following setting:

```
useLiveLayout=false
```